# Pushing a different commit to override previous commit on branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, fast-forward

Time for a noob question. Sorry if it seems too basic but had nowhere to turn, thanks in advance.

I created a branch to push my changes and worked on that branch for a while. But master updated meanwhile. I needed to pull the changes from master and then return to my branch, but revised some code in the process and now I cannot push to branch. I tried to read git manual and fast-forward section but it didn't seemed to make any sense at this point since I'm a bit new to git.

TLDR;

Master ------ Current State
            \
             \
              \
               \
                 Branch to be overriden

What I want to do is push my current stage to branch to be overriden without destroying the branch but content of the branch may be destroyed in the process it doesn't matter.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you only need to merge `master` into your branch, and then push normally:

```
# from your branch
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
# resolve any merge conflicts
git push origin yourBranch
```

At this point, your local `yourBranch` should be up to date with the latest changes from `master`.  If your feature is finished, you could setup a pull request going back to `master`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But conflict seems to be with the branch I'm trying to push.  
<br>
```hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind<br>
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.<br>
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.<br>```

Comment: @necrygor Yes, you have to resolve those merge conflicts.  Read the hint, it is telling you to pull.

Comment: I think you were right but I did something that I couldnt manage to take back, like branch was saying HEAD detached at ---... I ended up copying changed files to somewhere else, deleting branch from remote, than pulling from master and re-creating a branch, then making changes there. Lots of senseless steps...

Thank you for advice and your time though.

Comment: For the detached HEAD problem, you could have gotten back to your branch just by doing `git checkout yourBranch`.  But, I don't know all your details.